# Sending GIF images to WeChat

Tags: android, animated-gif, wechat

I am working on an Android app in which I am sending GIF images to WeChat. I am sending that image using `WeChatSDK` but the problem is that I am not able to see animated image, I'm getting that static image instead.

Answer (score 2):

You CAN send an animated GIF in WeChat.

- save the GIF as an image
- send the image

I have had mixed results with this method, but it does work with some GIF files

Answer (score 0):

Wechat only support GIF emotion, doesn't support GIF image. So it's impossible now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to realise that:

**the presentation on Wechat service account is not like one on a normal web browser.**

For example, you can only use `HTML` tag with text sent atm, and `Wechat` service account doesn't support any other `HTML` tags.

Do remind me if you know any other `HTML` tags or attributes supported, I was so devastated trying to implement coloured text.

And yes I agree with @Deco.